# Make 2 column layout. (similar to https://medium.com/ )

Tags: html, css

Trying to make 2 column layout. Example https://medium.com/

Left sidebar is not moving when you scroll. Also If your mouse is over the sidebar you cannot scroll the main content.

How can i implement it. I have been trying all day w0w.

Thanks

Comment: So you're looking for `position: fixed`?

Answer (score 1):

**[Working FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RvNab/1/)**

### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
        SIDE
    </div>
   <div class="main">
       CONTENT
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.main {
    background: red;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
.sidebar {
    background: blue;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
```